# Laravel 8 Routing Redirect to blank page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

I have tried several different methods with no success. I get a blank page. I want to redirect to a page after deleting a record from a controller. The Laravel docs say this; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#redirect-routes

```
Route::redirect('/here', '/there');
```

I have this

```
Route::redirect('customers', 'customer' );
```

I have also tried this, but get this error Route [customers] not defined.

```
return redirect()->route('customers');
```

The route in my web.php looks like this.

```
Route::get('/customers', [CustomersController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your index method ?

Comment: If you want to use `route()` helper, you need to name your route, like `Route::get('/customers', [CustomersController::class, 'index'])->name('customers.index');`

Comment: Then you should use `return redirect()->route('customers.index');` as explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-named-routes

Comment: I am not sure why this question was closed because all the other questions before do not answer this directly. I am still curious why the Laravel docs show the Redirect method and then it does not work. I also do not get the /here /there either. I assumed it from the page I am on to the page I want to go.

Comment: Thanks, miken32 because I have it redirecting now.